# rails 3.0.7 memory leak

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, memory-leaks

I have some strange issue with memory on my two different rails applications. Both application use rails 3.0.7. 
Each of controller request allocate 20-30-50 mb of memory. In production mode this amount decrease to 5-10. But this is the same things.

This is the list of gems which used by both of application:

```
gem 'pg' 
gem 'haml' 
gem 'sass' 
gem 'devise' 
gem 'simple_form' 
gem 'state_machine' 
gem "globalize3", "0.1.0.beta" 
gem "easy_globalize3_accessors" 
gem 'paperclip' 
gem 'andand'
```

Switching off all of this gems doesn't give me any results.  I try to use mysql instead of pg but result is same.

I make memprof and here it is -> http://memprof.com/dump/4dcbb1e37fdeb632fd000001

Maybe someone can look at memprof and give me any idea?

I know what i need to look at my code and try to find mistake, but this happend on two different (!!) rails application!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FYI, we had a similar issue, reverted back to Rails 3.05 and the memory leak/bloat went away. It has to do with garbage collection, I believe.